# How to find Windows SID from IE browser?

Tags: javascript, java, windows, internet-explorer, sid

I am trying to find a way to get windows SID of a user logged into a windows computer and accessing my web application via a Internet explorer browser. Is there a way to find out using Javascript ? Any answers would highly helpful.

Comment: You can't do that.

Comment: Can you please tell me why I can't do that ?

Comment: For security and privacy reasons.

Comment: Can you explain how java factors into this? I could probably show you in java if given more info about your need.